# "apt-get" not finding packages on Terminal

Tags: apt

I have been trying to install different packages via Terminal, like `laptop-mode-tools`, `xserver-xorg-input-multitouch` or `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack`, but it never works because I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
```

Normally I have been able to install this stuff through the Synaptic Package Manager, but I can't find there the "mtrack" driver.

Any idea why `apt-get` is not working? I have already run `sudo apt-get update` several times.

**EDIT:**
I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 in a MacBook Pro with dual boot (Leopard)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to BlueXrider, JasonD and CS I manage to install the packages I wanted. Apparently it was a problem of sources and package names. This is what I did:

I went to the Ubuntu-x-swat repository here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu-x-swat?dist=oneiric

Ran the instructions they provide there:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install <package name>`

And then, instead of the "package header" `xf86-input-mtrack` (I actually tried, but I still got the "unable to locate" error), installed the package `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack`

So, as I said before, it must have been a problem between sources and package names. I know have the mtrack driver working (which, again, makes the touchpad tab dissapear from the mouse settings....)

Comment: Good Job, atta-boy, congrats and Nice work!

Comment: Glad to hear the good news.  Is your new driver fitting your expectations (after tweaking)?  Also, apt-get seems to be working for you now that intalled that repository... I think maybe initially something was turned off for you for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you guys!

@CS It looks like it ;) I haven't tried your settings advice yet, but I think I like it. I'm too use to be able to mark the text just with the 2 fingers touchpad.

Answer (score 4):

First try searching with apt-cache, to find the exact match on the package you're interested in.

```
apt-cache search xserver-xorg-input
```

If the package you need isn't in the list then it's not available in the repositories your system has configured. On my system both laptop-mode-tools and xserver-xorg-input-multitouch are available, but not xserver-xorg-input-mtrack.

Searching google for 'ubuntu mtrack' leads to http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/natty/main/base/xserver-xorg-input-mtrack

This page show that the package (at least for ubuntu 11.04) is not in the main repository but is available via PPA xorg-edgers http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers?dist=natty

Follow the instructions there for enabling the PPA, note the name of the package is     xf86-input-mtrack

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xf86-input-mtrack
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and for writing all the steps. I run cahce and Mtrack wasn't there. I added the repository, updated and tried to install, and I still get the "Unable" error :S

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? When it comes to questions about packages, this is critical information as packages come and go, they get moved between repositories and can have different name between OS versions.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, sorry for leaving that out of the original question!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for multi-touch pad gesture driver for 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04

The packages are located here 
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/xserver-xorg-input-mtrack

#

############### UNOFFICIAL  REPOS

#

3rd Party Binary Repos

Xorg Edgers - https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers

## Run this command: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8844C542`

add this to your source.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
```

# 3rd Party Source Repos

Xorg Edgers (Source) - https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers

## Run this command: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8844C542`

add this to your source.list

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Managing repositories using command line https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite a newbie... how do I install the packages from there? Do I include a new source to `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Or do I download it from the website and install it other way?

Comment: so we can get the correct source....what release are you running? Natty? Percise? Oneiric?

Comment: Oneiric. I'm editing the original question to add that info :)

Comment: I tried, and after running those commands and adding the sources, running `get-apt update` and trying to install the driver again, this is what i got: `W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ oneiric/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_xorg-edgers_ppa_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems` and still `E: Unable to locate package xf86-input-mtrack
`

Comment: Done!!! See my reply below,  I wanna write all the commands I used ;)

Answer (score 0):

answered by OP
Thanks to BlueXrider, JasonD and CS I manage to install the packages I wanted. Apparently it was a problem of sources and package names. This is what I did:

I went to the Ubuntu-x-swat repository here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu-x-swat?dist=oneiric

Ran the instructions they provide there:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

And then, instead of the "package header" xf86-input-mtrack (I actually tried, but I still got the "unable to locate" error), installed the package xserver-xorg-input-mtrack

So, as I said before, it must have been a problem between sources and package names. I know have the mtrack driver working (which, again, makes the touchpad tab dissapear from the mouse settings....)