# Should I down-grade the version of ubuntu on my computer (12.04)?

Tags: command-line, bug-reporting

I've been having problems with terminal finding directories and packages on my computer & I'm not the only one. Aderojas has/had the same issue see link: [apt-get not finding packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104587/apt-get-not-finding-packages-on-terminal) I have tried every suggestion on this post & got the response:

```
no such file or directory
```

or some such similar response...

I'm thinking that others are successfully using these functions, why can't I? Is there some bug that needs to be worked out? Are others on a different version of Ubuntu successful running these processes? Maybe installing a different version of Ubuntu will solve these issues??? How should I proceed?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: can you describe how do you search for file or dir

Answer (score 0):

First read this: [UsingTheTerminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)
Then read this: [Apt-Get/How-to: Package management with APT](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto/)
And this also: [InstallingSoftware](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)

***And DO NOT downgrade your Ubuntu !!! :)***

Comment: @ swift: Thanks for the tips and the links! I'm going to check them out right now!